# Error correction : All the children have assembled on the ground and are waiting for the Principal to come

Tags: exam-questions

> All the children have assembled on the ground and are waiting for the Principal to come.

My book says the correction to above sentence is to replace *the principal to come* with *the principal's coming* but I doubt if its the correct correction. Please confirm if the book is correct or not, if correct then why ?

Comment: Actually, both **Principal to come** and **Principal's coming** are okay. However, the verb **assemble** is very awkward here.

Answer (score 1):

The principal's coming is uses the word "coming" as a noun. This is hardly ever used. I've lived in America my entire life and I doubt iv'e ever heard anyone say that. Saying `the principal to come` would be more correct.

Comment: "Waiting for the Principal's arrival" would work.